# using OR in egrep

Tags: grep

How do I select only the lines those start with any digit or "**** SETTLE" word with a few stars? 
Following will return the lines starting with number but do not return the lines with the word SETTLE.

```
# cat somefile.txt | egrep "(^[0-9]|'^*************** SETTLE ')"
```

Comment: How many of them? You need to escape your asterisks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
egrep "^(([0-9])|([*]{3,} SETTLE))"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ egrep '^([0-9]|\**+ SETTLE )' somefile.txt
```